# C# 8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm trying to use the office component to convert a excel file to a pdf file ,but I get the exception as blow

```
<exception><![CDATA[System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000401A): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A).
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
]]></exception>
```

However,when I restart the IIS ,everything is ok.And almost two days later,The Exception appear again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :) (such as code samples, context, more details about what you are trying to achieve, etc)